# How to target specific list indexes (JAVA)

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a boardame called Mancala and i want to change the winner() function.

The game ends if one side has no stones in either of their pits, then the winner is determined if PlayerOne's mancala has more stones than PlayerTwo's, or vice versa.

But i have no idea how to target a specific element in an object so i can extend the win function... Any help would be appreciated!

What i'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
if (sideOne.get(13).number > sideOne.get(14).number) {
    return...
}
```

I know the above code is incorrect, but i want to target is both the array lists, a specific index of that list and the integer element in the object.

I've included the constructors of the games board and the current winner() function.

Class of MancalaPit

```
public class MancalaPit {
    String player;
    Integer stones;
    Boolean pit;
    Integer number;
    MancalaPit next;

    public MancalaPit(String player, int stones, boolean pit, int number, MancalaPit next) {
        this.player = player;
        this.stones = stones;
        this.pit = pit;
        this.number = number;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public class Board { // Creates the board

    private MancalaPit a;
    private MancalaPit b;
    private MancalaPit c;
    private MancalaPit d;
    private MancalaPit e;
    private MancalaPit f;
    private MancalaPit mancalaOne;
    private MancalaPit g;
    private MancalaPit h;
    private MancalaPit i;
    private MancalaPit j;
    private MancalaPit k;
    private MancalaPit l;
    private MancalaPit mancalaTwo;
    private ArrayList<MancalaPit> sideOne;
    private ArrayList<MancalaPit> sideTwo;

    public Board() { // Constructs the bad boy

        // Constructs the array lists
        sideOne = new ArrayList<>();
        sideTwo = new ArrayList<>();

        // Constructs the pits and Mancala's
        a = new MancalaPit("playerOne", 4, false, 1, null);
        b = new MancalaPit("playerOne", 4, false, 2, null);
        c = new MancalaPit("playerOne", 4, false, 3, null);
        d = new MancalaPit("playerOne", 4, false, 4, null);
        e = new MancalaPit("playerOne", 4, false, 5, null);
        f = new MancalaPit("playerOne", 4, false, 6, null);
        mancalaOne = new MancalaPit("playerOne", 0, true, 13, null);
        g = new MancalaPit("playerTwo", 4, false, 7, null);
        h = new MancalaPit("playerTwo", 4, false, 8, null);
        i = new MancalaPit("playerTwo", 4, false, 9, null);
        j = new MancalaPit("playerTwo", 4, false, 10, null);
        k = new MancalaPit("playerTwo", 4, false, 11, null);
        l = new MancalaPit("playerTwo", 4, false, 12, null);
        mancalaTwo = new MancalaPit("playerTwo", 0, true, 14, null);

        // Constructs the order of the pits
        a.next = b;
        b.next = c;
        c.next = d;
        d.next = e;
        e.next = f;
        f.next = mancalaOne;
        mancalaOne.next = g;
        g.next = h;
        h.next = i;
        i.next = j;
        j.next = k;
        k.next = l;
        l.next = mancalaTwo;
        mancalaTwo.next = a;

        // Constructs sides
        sideOne.add(a);
        sideOne.add(b);
        sideOne.add(c);
        sideOne.add(d);
        sideOne.add(e);
        sideOne.add(f);
        sideTwo.add(g);
        sideTwo.add(h);
        sideTwo.add(i);
        sideTwo.add(j);
        sideTwo.add(k);
        sideTwo.add(l);

    }

    public String winner() {
        Boolean one = true;
        Boolean two = true;
        for(MancalaPit pit : sideOne) {
            if(pit.stones == 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                one = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(one == true) {
            return "Your boy player one is the champion";
        }
        for(MancalaPit pit : sideTwo) {
            if(pit.stones == 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                two = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(two == true) {
            return "Your boy player two is the champion";
        }

        return "No winners so far";
    }
```

Comment: sorry what do you want to do?

Comment: You can target a specific list index with `list.get(i)` where `i` is the index (if I understood the question correctly)

Comment: I essentially want to create an if statement in the winner() function like: if (MancalaOne > MancalaTwo) { return "Winner is..."; But i need to know how to target a specific index of a list, so in my case, i need to target index 13 and 14 to achieve what i want, if that makes any more sense @ScaryWombat

Comment: try reading the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Comment: Sounds guys, works perfectly. But i'm getting a 'The operator > is undefined for argument type(s) Mancala.MancalaPit, Mancala.MancalaPit'... Which is understandable, but how can i still target a specific index, but also target specific element in the objet? If you understand what i mean? I'd like to target a specific index, as well as the number of stones in the Mancala. If that makes sense? Sorry to be a pain

Comment: We don't know what is `MancalaPit`, could you post the source of it?

Comment: @Lennier It's at the bottom of the question, mate

Comment: I mean the source code of the class `MancalaPit`, can't see it at your question. If that is some third party library, you need to read it's documentation to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Really? Because it's there?

Comment: @Lennier It's now at the top of the code

Comment: If you want to get specific `MancalaPit` knowing pit's number, you better use `Map` instead of `ArrayList` to store pits as key-value pairs with it's numbers as keys. Then you can get the pit from the map by `map.get(number)` and then you can get `stones` from the specific pit as you've already done in your code.

Comment: i've thought about that and looked into it a little further, whilst it seems like it could help, ArrayList has a lot of functions that i need... such as next(), and i would have recode a lot of things. Maybe it is feasible with an array list and i'm not explaining myself. I'm going to explain what i want in better detail in the question (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to target an index at all (especially since these pits aren't in the lists you created), you already have variables defined to compare the win condition.  You should be able to just compare mancalaOne.stones to mancalaTwo.stones if either "one" is true or "two" is true.  BTW one and two should be booleans not Booleans.

i.e. do the two for loops, then do 
if (one || two) { 
   if (mancalaOne.stones > mancalaTwo.stones) {
       return "Player 1 wins!"
   } else if ...
}

Comment: It works! Cheers man! Only issue is that now, no win statement is returning haha